# Put ads in flat list every X items?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a flat list with many items. Would it be possible to break it every X items to put another components such as ads inside of it? I couldn't find it in official docs. Here is my flat list:

```
<FlatList
        ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooter}   
        removeClippedSubviews={true}
        data={this.state._data}
        renderItem={({item}) => {
            return (
           <View>
             ...
          {item.something}
              ...
        </View>
         );
          }}
         keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
        />
```

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, there is no such functionality build into `FlatList`.

However, one way of doing this would be to add the ads to the `data` that is passed into the `FlatList` and modify the `renderItem` function to also be able to render them.

E.g. the following code snippet would take an array of content and an array of ads and add an add after every 2 elements:

```
const ads = [...]; // array of ads
const content = [...]; // array of content
const alternate = 2;

const data = content.reduce((acc, curr, i) => {
  if ((i + 1) % alternate === 0) {
    const adIndex = Math.floor(i / alternate) % ads.length;
    return [...acc, curr, {...ads[adIndex], isAdd: true }];
  }

  return [...acc, curr];
}, []);
```

Then you could modify the `renderItem` function to render an add if the item is one, e.g.

```
({item}) => {
  if (item.isAdd) {
    // renderAdd
  } else {
    // renderContent
  }
}
```